# What is an operand?

Tags: bash, variable, arithmetic

I just want someone to explain what an "operand" is because I just don't understand it.  Here is the context I'm reading this in:

In [the section about *Shell Arithmetic* in the bash shell manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html):

> Shell variables are allowed as **operands**; parameter  expansion  is  performed before the expression is evaluated.  Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without  using  the  parameter expansion  syntax.

Comment: "an operand is the object of a mathematical operation, i.e., it is the object or quantity that is operated on." -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand

Comment: Right so it's just saying that I can use a variable to do math then?

Comment: right, pretty much. also the point about parameter expansion means that you can do something like `op=+; x=$(( a $op b ))`, or `expr=1+1; x=$(( $expr ))`. parameter expansion is done before the syntax of the expression is parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *operator* is an action that is performed on one or more *operands*.

For example, in the formula `3 + 4`, the plus symbol `+` is the operator and the values `3` and `4` are the operands.

With respect to your quote, "*Shell variables are allowed as operands*", this means that a shell variable may be used in such a formula, `a + 4`. Syntactically, this would be represented in `sh` script as `(( a + 4 ))`, and its value would be obtained as `$(( a + 4 ))`. Spaces are optional:

```
a=3
b=$((a+4))
echo "b=$b"    # outputs b=7
```

**Warning:** avoid using `$var` constructs inside `$(( … ))` if at all possible, as these are evaluated before the expression itself is considered. Example:

```
a='4+3'; echo "$(( a * 2 ))"    # returns "14", i.e. (4+3)*2
```

but

```
a='4+3'; echo "$(( $a * 2 ))"    # returns "10", i.e. 4+3*2
```

A similar expansion applies for `a=` (undefined or empty), which results in `0*2` for the first expression but `*2` (an error) for the second.

Comment: Beware that in `a=3+1`, `b=$(( $a * 2 )); echo "b=$b"`, you get `b=5` (`3 + 1 * 2`), not `b=8` (`(3+1)*2`), so that doc is slightly misleading.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas unintuitively `a=3+1; b=$((a*2)); echo "b=$b"` returns `8` but `a=3+1; b=$(($a*2)); echo "b=$b"` returns `5`. I'm just mulling over the reason why later evaluation would treat `a` as being mathematically `(3+1)` rather than syntactically `3+1`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, and roaima, I don't think it's too inconsistent. The parameter expansion is expanded before the arithmetic expression is evaluated, or parsed, so `$a * 2` becomes `3+1 * 2` which gives 5. But in `a * 2`, the value of the variable `a` is evaluated when it's used in the expression, so a=3+1 = 4, and then `a * 2` becomes `4 * 2` = 8. I'm not sure if the doc says that variables are evaluated recursively, but that's consistent with `a=b; b=c; c=9; echo $((a))` giving 9.